# How can I use libraries which were compiled by Intel compiler, when I'm using gcc?

Tags: c++, intel

I'm running on Linux and I got a library (.a) which was compiled by Intel compiler.

I'm trying to link against this static library (I'm using g++) and getting link error:

```
undefined reference to intel_fast_memcpy
```

I requested to get the library as a shared library (.so) which was compiled by intel compiler too, and I got the same error.

How can I use libraries which were compiled by Intel compiler, when I'm using gcc?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: does it mean object-compatibility? As far as I understood, it is only compatible with the GCC-source (at least for C++), which means able to interprete GCC-makros https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/512816

Comment: In the section "GCC* Compatibility and Interoperability" https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/522750 in the Intel C++ 15.0 compiler manual, which HighPerformanceMark was alluding to, it has directions for linking programs compiled using both gcc and icc. I skimmed through looking for an explicit statement saying that name mangling was the same. I didn't find that but given some of the libraries it cited, I think that is a safe assumption.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to link C++ client code against  C++ libraries built with different compiler (even same compiler name but different versions don't work). C++ -linkage is not stanrardised.

However, C-linkage is. If you wrap a library to export the symbols as C, (external "C"{ } - block in your code) you could use these libraries with any compiler, and even not only with C/C++; For doing this, the wrapper-lib should be built with intel-compiler in your case.

Comment: Thanks. So I will request to get the library as c library. Do I need to request to compile it with special flags ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Intel compiler. Tell the provider your gcc version and platform, they should know, what to do. However, using a C-library is of cause not as comfortable as C++. You'll need creator/destractor functions instead of c-tors, d-tors and manage the objects created inside the C++ library by handles (e.g. ints or names). If the application is big, I'd better considered to switch to the same compiler.

Comment: I have tried to use static c lib (.a) but same error